# AngularJS - Getting the Value from the first column of a row in a table on change event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

Please see plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0eP1AJ7Q59Otj7bJ4iP?p=preview) that demonstrates the issue:

I want to display the corresponding English value (first column) for any given row when any of the values are changed. So for example 'Uploaded' should always be displayed in the pop-up when any of the values on the second **row** are changed.

I have gotten this far in example, but not quite there:

```
<textarea ng-model="res.Value"
          ng-change="vm.changed(vm.resourceGridResources.Resources[$index].Resources[0].Value)"
          style="min-width: 300px"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your exemple.
Do not use `$index` but `$parent.$index`.
It will refers to the `$index` of the previous `ng-repeat`.

```
<textarea ng-model="res.Value"
          ng-change="vm.changed(vm.resourceGridResources.Resources[$parent.$index].Resources[0].Value)"
          style="min-width: 300px">
</textarea>
```

[Corrected plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqbiXJZOJVHctc4PdAjr?p=preview)